# Passing data from controller to MVC2 User Control

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a MVC2 user control that I want to dynamically load the menu from the controller.

I will use LINQ to SQL to get the data that I want to pass to the user control.

How can I tell the MVC2 User Control which controller and action to use?

This is in ASP.net MVC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Html.RenderAction` helper:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName"); %>
```

From your controller you should return a `PartialViewResult`:

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var menuItems = DB.GetMenuItems();
    return PartialView("MenuViewName", menuItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the controller tells which view to use and not vice versa.

But you can use the [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx) Html helper to call a child action which returns the concrete partial view